segment tree with range intersection
Recently I came up with a range problem when thinking about a hobby project.
Consider a big binary array indexed from 0 with size A("[0, A)"), I want to support 3 range (the ranges are defined to be "[left, right)" but isn't very important and can be changed on demand) operations:

RangeSet(v, left, right) that sets a range to a value. For example 00000 after RangeSet(1, 1, 3) would be 01100.
RangeIntersectQuery(left, right) which finds the intersection between a range and all the 1s(or 0s) in the array, then merging the result into a list of ranges. For example, RangeIntersectQuery(1, 5) on 011010010 would be a list of ranges ([1, 3), [4, 5)). I'm not sure whether the order of the ranges would matter in the future, but likely that the list can be degraded to an unordered collection.
RangeQuery(left, right) which checks if an interval is full of 1s(or 0s). For example, RangeQuery(3, 5) on 00010110 would be false while RangeQuery(5, 7) would be true.

Ideally, all operations only concerns 1s, but supporting 0s shouldn't create much trouble.
I was thinking that segment tree should be able to solve operation 1 and 3 in O(logA) time and O(k*A) total memory. However, I've trouble coming up with a good way to handle operation 2.
A can be up to 10^9. RangeSet's range length is likely at most 10^3. RangeQuery's length is probably around 10^6-10^7. RangeIntersectQuery's length should be around 10^8-10^9. I don't really want O(A) time on the 3 operations, I want them to be sublinear.
I'm looking for an algorithm/data structure that can solve my problem.

Operation 2 can produce linear-size output, so you can't really expect to do it in less than linear time.

@MattTimmermans Suppose I disregard operation 1 and store it using interval tree it can be less than linear. Problem is that interval tree doesn't work well with operation 1.

Operation 2 can be done using a segment tree in a best=average case sublinear and worst case linear approach. You start from the bottom layer(the layer with the smallest ranges) from left and traverse up until you find a range in a layer that's not all 1s(0s). Then, you go to the other child of this range and traverse down. During your way down, if the left child of the range is full of 1s(0s), you go to the right child, otherwise, you go down the left child. Basically, you try to fill the queried range with the largest full ranges(top layers) in the segment tree.
On average, this is less than O(A), but I'm not sure what exactly it's. However, if you are only concerned about the largest full range starting from left, this is the average case O(logA). The worst case happens when your bottom layer looks something like this 0101010101 where larger ranges on higher layers aren't full.
